# How to switch to edit mode of vi on mac terminal

Tags: macos, vim

I am new to mac, trying to edit a .gitignore file from the macbook terminal, I type

```
 vi .gitignore
```

it opens the file but not letting me switch to edit mode. How does vi switches mode on mac ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too basic usage of vi/vim. same as counting `ls` with `-l` to list file details into shell script/bash...

Comment: @Kent basic usage == off topic?

Comment: Can you edit your question to list the *exact* steps you used trying to enter edit mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On Mac you can more correctly type `vim` (Vi Improved) instead :)

Same as everywhere, `i` switches to "INSERT" mode and `ESC` switches back to command mode.

A good learning resource for Vim is included in Mac. Simply type `vimtutor` and it will teach you quickly how to use vim effectively.

Another editing option on mac is `nano` it is a command line text editor that is much easier for those familiar with TextEdit/Notepad.

Comment: There is no difference. `vi` is a link to `vim`. Do an `ls -l /usr/bin/vi` :)

Answer (score 12):

Same as everywhere. `i` to insert. `Esc` to go back to command mode, `:wq` to save and quit.

By the way, if you're uncomfortable with `vi`, try [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), I love it :) It's GUI based, though.

Comment: I heard many positive comments to sublime text2 too. also some of my colleagues are using it everyday. I believe it is a good editor. I want to give it a try, however vim doesn't give me a chance. :)